# Is there a Windows 8 App directory website (not the one accessible from within Windows 8)?

Tags: windows-8

Is going through the Windows Shop within Windows 8 the only way to know about the apps that are currently available (and if an app idea is already taken)? I've seen Windows 8 app links like this one -
http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/en-in/app/bigflix/cd3aa73b-e60e-44b6-bbe9-6898050a3502

...but going to the root site throws a "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied" and a search for "Windows 8 Store" doesn't provide any useful results. I guess there will be something after the official Windows 8 launch but is there anything else I'm missing? As a developer, I would love to see a summary listing of apps that shows a brief description, its features and Capabilities used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update - It is now possible to search for [Windows Store](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/search#q=top+free&s=Store) & [Windows Phone apps](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/featured-apps) even from non-Windows 8 machines and also view apps by category from the official Microsoft websites.

As @mamata-dalal & @gyurisc have mentioned, there is currently no official Windows 8 app directory.

I came across the website [Windows8Apps](http://www.windows8apps.com/) (though not perfect) that comes close to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately for us, Microsoft is not providing any such information regarding the Store apps. All we can do is glean a bit from here and there. Zdnet has mentioned the number of apps, for example.

Have a look [here](http://www.zdnet.com/with-a-month-to-go-until-windows-8s-launch-2000-plus-windows-store-apps-7000004790/) and [here](http://www.winappupdate.com/welcome-to-winappupdate/)

This [link](http://www.directionsonmicrosoft.com/update/92-september-2012/3787-windows-storethe-state-of-the-store.html?start=1) in particular maybe of some use because it provides estimated app category breakdown.

Answer (score 2):

I created site http://metrostorescanner.com/ to see what's new in apps for all countries (but you can also use country filter).

Answer (score 1):

I found a file with a site map that you may be able to use for a listing of apps:
http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/sitemap/sitemap_1.xml

Comment: Nice find. The file was all of 6MB. Going by the name, I guess it was meant for search engines. I didn't know sitemaps could be that big.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.greatwindowsapps.com is a searchable directory on the web.  It's not the entire Store, the content is filtered to remove poor quality apps.  Disclosure: this is my site, so clearly I think that's an advantage :)

http://drunktester.azurewebsites.net/ is the full Store using the Australian content.  He published the source code (https://github.com/VikingCode/DrunkStore) so you could set this up for any country if you wished.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no other place than the Windows 8 Store is the only place, but I am sure soon there will be plenty of sites categorizing these apps.