# API to access Windows Store

Tags: windows-store

Does windows store has an API?

For example when you open the "store" app, there is a "top free" list that will show the top 100 most popular free apps. Is the list coming from an HTTP endpoint somewhere on the internet?

Comment: Some related questions: http://superuser.com/questions/490202/can-i-browse-the-windows-app-store-outside-of-windows-8 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618684/is-there-a-windows-8-app-directory-website-not-the-one-accessible-from-within-w

Answer (score 0):

There is no official API for accessing content in the Windows Store. I'm sure that the content is being pulled in from the web via and HTTP or HTTPS endpoint but using an undocumented service like this would likely not be recommended. It also doesn't look like there is a protocol activation schema documented for launching the store. The closest thing I can find is the MarketplaceDetailTask in Windows Phone. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.marketplacedetailtask(v=vs.105).aspx

The only other supported way of launching the store would be by using links to apps which cause the store to open.